Horror from the 1970s
I'm trying to identify something I watched in Canada in the 1970s. It was either a film or an episode of a TV show and may have been in black and white.
I think it was set in an old manor house (so quite possibly it was British). There was a scene in it when someone was looking up a hill into a forest and suddenly from behind the trees (which were backlit) in the distance stepped the silhouettes of people (witches?).
I associate it with a film in which every morning a bloodstain reappears on a floor or rug (but they may be two different films).

The reoccurring blood stain happens in The Canterville Ghost. It re-appears every morning on a rug despite being scrubbed away. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090792/
